# Cookies not working across different browsers

Tags: php, session, setcookie

I finally got my code working for a password protect script. It's still in its infancy, so I understand it isn't secure. My problem is that I seem to have problems across a number of different computers and browsers. From what I've seen, firefox has no problem with the cookies being set. I'm running into trouble on certain machines not setting cookies.

What I've seen is that on one machine, I have a system with ie, chrome, and firefox. The cookies don't work on chrome, but work with ie and firefox. On my linux machine, firefox works without a hitch. I don't have chrome installed on it so, I can't test that. Then on another machine, ie doesn't want to work with the website. I would think that it's a problem with the privacy settings, but it appears that they are all the same.

The odd thing about the chrome problem, is that I can see the cookie for the session, but I can't see the cookie that I set. So, obviously that is a problem, but I don't know why. I have the same problem with IE. I've set the IE machines to accept all cookies and have had no luck. The chrome browser is set to "Allow local data to be set".

Thanks in advance

```
      if (isset($_COOKIE["Cookie"])){
        FormatScreen();
      }
      else if ($_POST['access_password']){
        $PasswordEntered = crypt($_POST['access_password'],$salt);
        if ($PasswordEntered == $RealPassword){
            setcookie("Cookie", $PasswordEntered, time()+600, '/');
            FormatScreen();
        }
        else{
            echo LoginScreen();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps highlight the code where you think it might go wrong, it's kind of a pain to read through the whole thing.

Comment: functions defined in side case, didn't know that was valid.

Comment: @Bono Chopped it down to the problem area.

Comment: @Dagon What is "side case"? Never heard that one before...

Comment: @DaveRandom "inside". Before he removed it, his code had many functions defined inside a case\switch block, sure it works but is terrible to debug.

Comment: @Dagon I'm new relatively new to coding, so I'll take that comment and try to remember to set functions for global usage rather within specific parts of the code.

Comment: @pr- As a general rule the only time a function should be anywhere inside a block is `if (!function_exists())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using session cookies - look at [`http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

It will help improve security as the session is stored on the server and can't be tampered with. PHP then handles the session cookies on the client.

Comment: [Read why refering to this website is not a good idea](http://w3fools.com/). THe official PHP manual will give you excellent and up to-date information: [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: @John Wheal That tutorial helped me do exactly what I needed it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess No solution for that so I am suggesting  another solution to fix your problem  :

- You can also  use Sessions in server side . So if user not accept cookie he can't have permission to decline sessions because it's on server side .
- Make life time for session  .

I hope u find helpful in my comment .

Comment: What would be the best way to do this? Assign a session based on the ip address of the user?

Answer (score 0):

This is my corrected code.

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        echo "You are already logged in.";
      }
      else if ($_POST['access_password']){
        $PasswordEntered = crypt($_POST['access_password'],$salt);
        if ($PasswordEntered == $RealPassword){
            $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;
            //echo "Logged In=". $_SESSION['loggedin'];

            echo "You are now logged in!";
        }
        else{
            echo LoginScreen();
        }
      }
```